# Novice question about mid-rise quantization

Tags: quantization

Accoarding to [wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(signal_processing)#Mid-riser_and_mid-tread_uniform_quantizers), the function for quantization has the ceiling of x/Ds. 
Is this the ceiling of something multiplied by Ds?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify what $x$ and $D_s$ are, so your question is self-contained.